# MySQL Retrieving values with intermediary table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following tables:

MONKEY :

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Mary |

CHECK :

| id | monkey_id | checkdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-06-02 03:00:00 |
| 2 | 2 | 2023-08-24 14:30:00 |
| 3 | 1 | 2023-06-04 14:35:00 |

MEASUREMENTS :

| id | check_id | length | width | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 23.34 | 6.34 | 3.2 |
| 2 | 1 | 23.87 | 6.22 | NULL |
| 3 | 1 | 24.3 | 6.10 | NULL |
| 4 | 2 | 27.8 | 7.4 | NULL |
| 5 | 2 | 27.56 | 7.62 | NULL |

XMITTER :

| id | check_id | channel | tune | attachstart | attachfinish | removed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 534 | 2 | 2023-08-24 14:30:32 | 2023-08-24 14:45:00 | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | 532 | 1 | 2023-06-02 03:31:00 | 2023-06-02 03:35:00 | 2023-06-10 14:45:00 |

How would I retrieve a monkey with:

1. Date of most recent check
2. Multiple sets of length/width measurements are taken at the same time (and joined by check_id) - I would like to return the average of the most recent length/width measurements and weight which is usually only taken once during a check.
3. The current transmitter if one is attached. A transmitter is attached if it doesnt have a removed date.

EXAMPLE RESULT SET :

| monkey.id | last_check_date | newest_avg_length | newest_avg_width | newest_avg_width | channel | tune | channel_attach_start |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-06-04 | 23.82 | 6.20 | 3.2 | 532 | 1 | 2023-06-02 |

There should be one result set for each monkey.

I have created a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/949f42) - which is same structure (slightly different data).

*NB: The most recent measurements is on check 1. The most recent xmitter is on check 3.

Comment: your example result shows the xmitter that *does* have a removed date, but it sounded like you only want ones with no removed date

Comment: Edited to make bird one has had 2 xmitters . Only want to return the current xmitter (if there is one). Current is not just newest date, but must be NULL on removed date).

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? Please update either the sample data (and expected result) in your question or the fiddle, so they match up. Your fiddle does not have `tx.tune`. Is it correct that there can only ever be zero or one tx attached to a given `monkey_id`? Your example has `id` and `health_check_date` being out of sequence, presumably this is not the case in the real data, and we can rely on `MAX(id)` and `MAX(health_check_date)` always being in the same record for a given `monkey_id`?

Answer (score 3):

This query assumes:

1. every monkey has at least one `health_check` and set of `measurements`
2. there can only ever be zero or one transmitter attached per monkey

Let's start by getting the most recent `health_check`. As `id` and `health_check_date` are not in sequence, we need to get the maximum `health_check_date` per `monkey_id` and then join back to the `health_check` table to get the `id`, to then join to `measurements`. With an index on `(monkey_id, health_check_date)` the inner query does not need to read from the clustered index:

```sql
SELECT
    hc.monkey_id,
    hc_max.last_check_date,
    AVG(length) AS newest_avg_length,
    AVG(width) AS newest_avg_width,
    AVG(weight) AS newest_avg_weight
FROM health_check hc
JOIN (
    SELECT monkey_id, MAX(health_check_date) AS last_check_date
    FROM health_check
    -- WHERE monkey_id = 2 /* Uncomment this line if for specific monkey */
    GROUP BY monkey_id
) hc_max
    ON hc.monkey_id = hc_max.monkey_id
    AND hc.health_check_date = hc_max.last_check_date
JOIN measurements ms
    ON hc.id = ms.health_check_id
GROUP BY hc.monkey_id;
```

You can achieve the same using a window function but it carries a significantly greater overhead. I am including this as an option so you can test it against your data:

```sql
SELECT
    monkey_id,
    health_check_date AS last_check_date,
    AVG(length) AS newest_avg_length,
    AVG(width)  AS newest_avg_width,
    AVG(weight) AS newest_avg_weight
FROM (    
    SELECT hc.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY hc.monkey_id ORDER BY hc.health_check_date DESC) rn
    FROM health_check hc
) x
JOIN measurements m ON x.id = m.health_check_id
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY x.id;
```

Using one of the above queries as a derived table, you can then `LEFT JOIN` to `transmitter` via `health_check`, to get the current tx.

```sql
SELECT
    latest_health_check.monkey_id,
    latest_health_check.last_check_date,
    latest_health_check.newest_avg_length,
    latest_health_check.newest_avg_width,
    latest_health_check.newest_avg_weight,
    tx.channel,
    tx.offset,
    DATE(tx.attach_start) AS channel_attach_start
FROM (
    -- Derived table for the latest check.
    SELECT
        hc.monkey_id,
        hc_max.last_check_date,
        AVG(length) AS newest_avg_length,
        AVG(width) AS newest_avg_width,
        AVG(weight) AS newest_avg_weight
    FROM health_check hc
    JOIN (
        SELECT monkey_id, MAX(health_check_date) AS last_check_date
        FROM health_check
        -- WHERE monkey_id = 2 /* Uncomment this line if for specific monkey */
        GROUP BY monkey_id
    ) hc_max
        ON hc.monkey_id = hc_max.monkey_id
        AND hc.health_check_date = hc_max.last_check_date
    JOIN measurements ms
        ON hc.id = ms.health_check_id
    GROUP BY hc.monkey_id
) latest_health_check
LEFT JOIN transmitter tx
    ON EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM health_check hc
        WHERE hc.id = tx.health_check_id
        AND hc.monkey_id = latest_health_check.monkey_id
    )
    AND tx.removed IS NULL;
```

And, [here is an updated version of your fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/949f42/57)

P.S. It only returns for monkey_id 2, as this is the only monkey with measurements for its most recent check.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
  m.id AS monkey_id,
  MAX(h.health_check_date) AS last_check_date,
  AVG(me.length) AS newest_average_length,
  AVG(me.width) AS newest_average_width,
  AVG(me.weight) AS newest_avg_weight,
  t.channel AS channel,
  t.offset AS tune,
  t.attach_start AS channel_attach_start
FROM
  monkeys m
 JOIN
  health_check h ON h.monkey_id = m.id
 JOIN
  measurements me ON me.health_check_id = h.id
 JOIN
  transmitter t ON t.health_check_id = h.id AND t.removed IS NULL

GROUP BY
  m.id, m.name
ORDER BY
  m.id;
```

Comment: The most recent measurements and most recent xmitter may be on separate checks. Newest measurements were associated with check 1, newest transmitter on check 3.

Comment: The newest changes query you can see in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/949f42/22

Comment: I do not understand why there is not a result for two monkeys with this query as two of them have NULLs for removed date.

Comment: because of the Aggregate Functions used in the query they are returning only one value.

Comment: Which aggregate function is causing this? I am looking to do something similar.

Comment: I do not think this query is correct, it just selecting the max health check and null removed date. Sometimes the newest measurements is NOT on the newest health check